# How to get value from form control?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

How to get value from StringEdit control in x++ and insert it to new record?

Now I have:

```
ttsBegin;    
update_recordSet _empl setting Name=<and here goes input from control>
    where _empl.RecId==pole;   
ttsCommit;
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not how things work in AX, but if you insists:

```
update_recordSet _empl setting Name = nameCtrl.text()
    where _empl.RecId == pole;
```

The `nameCtrl` control can be declared by setting the `AutoDeclation` attribute to Yes.

That said, it might be easier [to make the control bound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa844912.aspx) to the table field.